# Windows Network Connection has filled systray with many icons

Tags: networking, troubleshooting, windows

I have a user that has a crazy amount of network connections populating his systray and he only has one network card and a wireless card.    After a while he can hover over them and they will disappear.

Any ideas if this is OS or driver related?

[alt text http://www.tekconxus.com/screenshot.png](http://www.tekconxus.com/screenshot.png)

Comment: I should note that all our users use the same disk image with identical hardware.  This is the only user experiencing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this problem and found that it was a result of a virus.  Do a full system anti-virus and spyware scan and see if it catches anything.  We had a tough time clearing it out and decided to just re-image the machine and all was well again.

Comment: +1 because while I am not convienced that this is a virus, the behavior is so weird, if I was responsible for the machine and I was convinced there was a good backup handy, I would blow it away as well.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the properties of 'My Network Places' and disable any invalid or unneeded network interfaces.  Assuming nothing breaks as a result, these should be safe to delete.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the physical cable on any wired connections to ensure they are making good contact with both the NIC and the remote end (wall, switch, etc.).  For the wireless connection, if it's an external device, check the USB connection and ensure it is working properly as well, perhaps switch it to a different port.  If that doesn't help, reinstall the drivers for the network devices.  Also be sure there are no IP address conflicts on the network that could be mucking it up.

Comment: I will check this out.

Answer (score 0):

What processes are running when this happens?  When you restart the machines do the icons go away?  I have had this happen a time or two, but a restart aways resolved it.

THis is from: http://www.techspot.com/vb/topic96802.html

this behaviour of try icons usually happens when their 'source' got updated or renewed. for example mcafee vscan updates itself from time to time depending on the settings. the old tray icon stays striked through and a new one appears. when you try to hover the old one it will disappear.
in your case with network connections its weird indeed. the only conclusive explanation would be that the network connection got lost and was renewed a couple of times. maybe the screensaver was active? so that the desktop, taskbar and tray were not refreshed. you could check the event log for network errors and try to find updated drivers for the network card.
I don't think you have troubles with viruses or any malicious software but do a full scan with a good and uptodate scanner. maybe try mcafee stinger or rootkit detective.